# Llamar base de datos con (this) en fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite, android-fragment

Estoy tratando de hacer un catalogo al enlazame con una base de datos que se encuentra en el folder assets, para que se muestre en un recycleview.
Esta actividad ya funciona por si sola pero ahora que la quiero incrustar en un fragment no puedo (soy algo nuevo en esto).
Alguien sabe como se adapta al fragment??

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
public static ArrayList<DictObjectModel> data;
DatabaseHelper db ;
ArrayList<String> nombrelist;
ArrayList<String> descripcionlist;
LinkedHashMap<String,String> namelist;
SearchView searchView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    db= new DatabaseHelper(this);
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Buscar");
    searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    data = new ArrayList<DictObjectModel>();
    fetchData();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return  false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            newText = newText.toLowerCase();

            final ArrayList<DictObjectModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<DictObjectModel>();

            for (int i = 0; i < nombrelist.size(); i++) {

                final String text = nombrelist.get(i).toLowerCase();
                if (text.contains(newText)) {

                    filteredList.add(new DictObjectModel(nombrelist.get(i),descripcionlist.get(i)));
                }
            }
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(filteredList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void fetchData()
{
    db =new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {

        db.createDataBase();
        db.openDataBase();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    namelist=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    int ii;
    SQLiteDatabase sd = db.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sd.query("Productos" ,null, null, null, null, null, null);
    ii=cursor.getColumnIndex("nombre");
    nombrelist=new ArrayList<String>();
    descripcionlist= new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        namelist.put(cursor.getString(ii), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("descripcion")));
    }
    Iterator entries = namelist.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry thisEntry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
        nombrelist.add(String.valueOf(thisEntry.getKey()));
        //QUITAR el -
        descripcionlist.add(""+String.valueOf(thisEntry.getValue()));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nombrelist.size(); i++) {
    data.add(new DictObjectModel(nombrelist.get(i), descripcionlist.get(i)));
    }

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Gracias.

Comment: Antes de todo puedes explicar cual es el error que pasa?, puedes mostrar cual es código de la base de datos? No podremos ayudarte si no das una explicación mas especifica de lo que pasa con la app

Answer (score 1):

Recientemente he tenido problemas con los fragments por cuestiones como la tuya si no he entendido mal.

Te pongo unos ejemplos y espero que te sirvan para solucionar tu problema:

Si por ejemplo, tienes un Toast en tu Main activity:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Estoy en el Main Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

como veras se usa el this.

Si ese mismo Toast lo quieres poner en un fragment:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ahora estoy en el Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

podrás comprobar que el this, ha cambiado por getContext()

Por otra parte, si lo que necesitas es trabajar con el View, en el fragment aparentemente no te lo detecta.

Si te fijas, al crear un fragment, android-studio te lo crea con el siguiente codigo:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vestidos, container, false);;
}
```

Para conseguir trabajar con el view, entonces seria tan senzillo como hacer lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vestidos, container, false);

    /*Tu codigo aquí*/

    return v;
}
```

De este modo cuando necesites el view, tu view será la variable v

Espero que te sirvan los ejemplos que te he dado ^_^

Comment: Si te ha resuelto el problema, por favor marca la respuesta como correcta y comentanos como te ha ido.

Answer (score 0):

En fragment se llama la base de datos con getActivity(), donde se pone (this) normalmente.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_historial, container, false);
        myDataset = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = vista.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        llenarLista();

        return vista;

    }

    private void llenarLista() {
        try {

            SQLiteProcesos sqLiteProcesos = new SQLiteProcesos(getActivity(), "Administrador", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase baseDeDatosProceso = sqLiteProcesos.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor fila = baseDeDatosProceso.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM procesos", null);

            if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hay datos ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Insertar datos desde la base de datos

            } else {

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        headerAdapter = new HeaderAdapter(myDataset);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(headerAdapter);

    }
```